# Rails: How to avoid this redirect loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

I'd like to force a user to change their password on login (assuming they've got a certain boolean marker set to true).

Right now I'm trying to do it via a `before_filter` called `change_password_check` that's in `ApplicationController`.

```
def change_password_check
  if current_user.change_password == true
    flash[:notice] = "You must be update your password before continuing"
    redirect_to change_password_path
    return false
  end
end
```

The problem, obviously, is that I get a redirect loop.

So, how can I only do that `before_filter` if the user is NOT on the `change_password_check` route (or posting to `user#update`)?

I'm running Rails 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
before_filter :change_password_check, :except => :change_password
```

You can specify only and except as options to the before_filter.  These accept an array of arguments, in the above case, you only have one method you wish to skip, however if you had another method that was to be skipped (your update action), you can do:

```
before_filter :change_password_check, :except => [:change_password, :update]
```

Only is the opposite of except, so:

```
before_filter :change_password_check, :only => :check_me
```

Would only be run if the method is check_me.

Comment: Don't know why I was thinking `except` and `only` didn't work in `ApplicationController`...seems they do though. :) Thanks!